# Html Report for TSLint

Tags: angular, npm, tslint

I am trying to create an html report for the "TSLint" task, I was able to generate a report for "JSHint" by installing the following package and making use of it subsequently. Not been able to find a similar reporter for TSLint.

*"npm install gulp-jshint-html-reporter --sav"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know i'm very late to answer this, but this might help you or someone else out who might still be searching:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-html-report

You can easily wire it up in a gulp task